WPF Drag and drop - System.InvalidOperationException. Dispatcher processing has been suspended, but messages are still being processed
I'm trying to make a window with two panels between which TextBoxes can be moved.
My code:
MainWindow.xaml
<Window x:Class="DragAndDropTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DragAndDropTest"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Width="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                AllowDrop="True" Drop="StackPanel_Drop">
            <TextBox IsReadOnly="True"  Text="Test1" MouseMove="TextBox_MouseMove" PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="TextBox_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" />
            <TextBox IsReadOnly="True" Text="Test2" MouseMove="TextBox_MouseMove" PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="TextBox_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown"/>
            <TextBox IsReadOnly="True" Text="Test3" MouseMove="TextBox_MouseMove" PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="TextBox_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown"/>
        </StackPanel>

        <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Width="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                AllowDrop="True" Drop="StackPanel_Drop">
            <TextBox IsReadOnly="True" Text="Test4" MouseMove="TextBox_MouseMove" PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="TextBox_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown"/>
            <TextBox IsReadOnly="True" Text="Test5" MouseMove="TextBox_MouseMove" PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="TextBox_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown"/>
            <TextBox IsReadOnly="True" Text="Test6" MouseMove="TextBox_MouseMove" PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="TextBox_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>

MainWindow.xaml.cs
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace DragAndDropTest
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private TextBox draggedTextBox;
        
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void TextBox_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            draggedTextBox = sender as TextBox;
        }

        private void TextBox_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed && draggedTextBox != null)
            {
                draggedTextBox.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
                {
                    DragDrop.DoDragDrop(draggedTextBox, draggedTextBox.Text, DragDropEffects.Move);
                });
            }
        }

        private void StackPanel_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Text))
            {
                string text = (string)e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Text);

                if (sender != draggedTextBox.Parent)
                {
                    var stackPanel = sender as StackPanel;
                    if (stackPanel != null)
                    {
                        var textBox = new TextBox { Text = text };
                        stackPanel.Children.Add(textBox);
                    }

                    var originalStackPanel = draggedTextBox.Parent as StackPanel;
                    if (originalStackPanel != null)
                    {
                        originalStackPanel.Children.Remove(draggedTextBox);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

When I try to drag an element to second panel, I get an exception:
System.InvalidOperationException. Dispatcher processing has been suspended, but messages are still being processed in TextBox_MouseMove method
line: DragDrop.DoDragDrop(draggedTextBox, draggedTextBox.Text, DragDropEffects.Move);
I can't find a solution on the Internet.
Can you tell me what I did wrong?
Regards

In your repro project you're using TextBox but you made them all read only. If you really don't need them to be able to be changed then use a TextBlock and the exception goes away.
I had a similar issue with my TextBox components within a ListBox. If you must use a TextBox then the issue is that the TextBox is trying to perform it's own drag/drop logic, and the additional drag/drop that you're doing is causing the crash. Running logic on the UI thread doesn't help. In my case I checked the visual tree under the mouse when the drag operation starts (PreviewMouseMove), and if it's a TextBox then I just return without doing the DoDragDrop opeation. This seems similar to what mm8 suggested, but that suggestion didn't work for me. It seems counter intuitive, but after that I could still drag from the text box, so some magic is happening to enable that. I am not a WPF expert; just sharing my experience.
Also, to really simplify things, I recommend using https://www.nuget.org/packages/gong-wpf-dragdrop. I put it in, set a few properties, and it just worked.

Hi I think problem is in the Dispatcher.Invoke call could you please try direct call the method DragDrop.DoDragDrop without calling from UI Thread , Its create issue may be that cause the InvalidOperationException.
Thanks

Your event handlers interfere with the default behaviour of the TextBox control.
The easiest way to work around this by opting out of the default behaviour would be to set the Handled property of the MouseButtonEventArgs to true in your TextBox_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown event handler:
private void TextBox_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    draggedTextBox = sender as TextBox;
    e.Handled = true;
}

Then you can also remove the superfluous call to Dispatcher.Invoke:
private void TextBox_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed && draggedTextBox != null)
    {
        DragDrop.DoDragDrop(draggedTextBox, draggedTextBox.Text, DragDropEffects.Move);

    }
}

